# Hashmap in C sorting the keys in alphabetic order when it shouldn't do that

Tags: c, linked-list, hashmap

I am a Mechanical Engineer student and I have to take this obligatory course on C programming, which I do not know a lot about. One of the assignments is to create a hashmap. Now a lot of my code is the work of copy-pasting from different tutorial sites, since the course professor told us to teach ourselves how to program in C and didn't explain anything but the mere basics.

This is my code up till now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "hashmap.h"


size_t key_space_global;

char *strdup (const char *s) {
    char *d = malloc (strlen (s) + 1);   
    if (d == NULL) return NULL;          
    strcpy (d,s);                        
    return d;                            
}

struct Bucket {
    const char* key;
    void* data;
    struct Bucket *next;
};

struct HashMap {
    size_t key_space;
    Bucket **hash_table;
    hashfunc hash;
};

unsigned int hash(const char *key) {
    unsigned int length, sum = 0, i;
    length = strlen(key);
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sum = sum + key[i];
    }
    return (sum%key_space_global);
}

HashMap *create_hashmap(size_t key_space) {
    if(key_space < 1){
        printf("invalid size");
        return NULL;
    }
    HashMap *pointer = calloc(1, sizeof(HashMap));
    pointer -> key_space = key_space;
    key_space_global = key_space;
    pointer -> hash = hash;
    pointer -> hash_table = malloc(sizeof(Bucket*)*key_space);
    unsigned int i;
    for(i = 0; i < key_space; i++){
        pointer -> hash_table[i] = NULL;
    }
    return pointer;
}

Bucket *create_bucket(const char *key, void *data) {
    Bucket *pointer = calloc(1,sizeof(Bucket));
    pointer -> key = strdup(key);
    pointer -> data = data;
    pointer -> next = NULL;
    return pointer;
}

void insert_data(HashMap *hm , const char *key,void *data, void*  (*resolve_collision)(void *old_data, void *new_data)) {
    unsigned int index = hm -> hash(key);
    if(hm -> hash_table[index] == NULL){
        hm -> hash_table[index] = create_bucket(key,data);
    }else{ 
        Bucket *next = hm -> hash_table[index] -> next;
        while(next != 0){
            if(strcmp(key, hm -> hash_table[index] -> key) == 0){
                resolve_collision(next -> data, data);
                return;
            }
            next = next -> next;
        } 
        next = create_bucket(key,data);
        next -> next = hm -> hash_table[index]; 
        hm -> hash_table[index] = next; 
    }
}

void* get_data(HashMap *hm, const char *key) {
    unsigned int index;
    index = hm -> hash(key);
    Bucket *pointer = hm -> hash_table[index];
    if(pointer == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }else if(pointer != NULL){
        Bucket *next = hm -> hash_table[index];
        while(next != NULL){
            if(strncmp(hm -> hash_table[index] -> key, key, 5) == 0) {
                return pointer -> data;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void iterate(HashMap *hm, void (*callback)(const char *key, void *data)){
unsigned int i;
    for(i = 0; i < hm -> key_space; i++){
        Bucket *pointer;
        for(pointer = hm -> hash_table[i]; pointer !=NULL; pointer = pointer -> next){
            callback(pointer -> key,pointer -> data);
        }
    }
}

void remove_data(HashMap *hm, const char key[], void (*destroy_data)(void* data)) {
    unsigned int index = hm -> hash(key);
    Bucket *temp;
    Bucket *next = hm -> hash_table[index];
    if(hm -> hash_table[index] == NULL){
        return;
    }else{ 
        while(next != NULL){
            if(strcmp(key, next -> key) == 0){
                if(destroy_data != NULL){
                    destroy_data(next -> data);
                }
                temp = next;
                free(next -> next);
                next -> next = NULL;
                free(next -> key);
                next -> key = NULL;
                hm -> hash_table[index] -> key = NULL;
                free(next); 
            }
            next = NULL;
            hm -> hash_table[index] = NULL;
        }
    }
}

void delete_hash_table(HashMap *hm) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < hm -> key_space; ++i) {
        Bucket *pointer;
        Bucket *next;
        for (pointer = hm -> hash_table[i]; pointer != NULL; pointer = next) {
            free(pointer -> key);
            pointer -> key = NULL;
            next = pointer -> next;
            free(pointer);
        }
        hm -> hash_table[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void delete_hashmap(HashMap *hm, void (*destroy_data)(void* data)) {
    if(hm == NULL)
    return;
    if(destroy_data != NULL){
        destroy_data(hm -> hash);
        hm -> hash = NULL;
        free(create_hashmap(hm -> key_space));
        delete_hash_table(hm);
    }
    free(hm -> hash_table);
    free(hm);
}
```

With it the following h-file:

```
#ifndef HASHMAP_H_INCLUDED
#define HASHMAP_H_INCLUDED

typedef unsigned int(*hashfunc)(const char*);

typedef struct Bucket Bucket;

typedef struct HashMap HashMap;

unsigned int hash(const char key[]);

HashMap *create_hashmap(size_t key_space);

typedef void* (*ResolveCollisionCallback)(void *old_data, void * new_data);

void insert_data(HashMap *hm , const char key[],void *data, void* (*resolve_collision)(void *old_data, void *new_data));

void* get_data(HashMap *hm, const char key[]);

void iterate(HashMap *hm, void (*callback)(const char *key, void *data));

typedef void (*DestroyDataCallback);

void remove_data(HashMap *hm, const char key[], void (*destroy_data)(void* data));

void delete_hashmap(HashMap *hm, void (*destroy_data)(void* data));

#endif
```

And it has to pass this test program the professor has provided:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "hashmap.h"

#ifdef COUNTING_WORDS
#include "wordcount.h"
#endif

size_t mystrlen(const char *str) {
    return strlen(str) + 1;
}

void print_element(const char *key, void *data) {
    printf("(\"%s\", %s)\n", key, (char*)data);
}

void *resolve_collision(void *old_value, void *new_value) {
    return new_value;
}

unsigned your_own_hash(const char *key) {
    return (unsigned) strlen(key) + (unsigned) *key;
}

int main() {
    unsigned int key_space = 1024;
    HashMap * hm = create_hashmap(key_space);

    char * string_1 = "TI2725-C";
    char * string_2 = "Embedded";
    char * string_3 = "Software";
    const char * key_1    = "ab";
    const char * key_2    = "cd";
    const char * key_3    = "ad";
    const char * key_4    = "xy";

    // Insert ("ab" -> "TI2725-C").
    insert_data(hm, key_1, string_1, resolve_collision);
    assert(memcmp(get_data(hm, key_1), string_1, mystrlen(string_1)) == 0);

    // Insert ("cd" -> "Embedded").
    insert_data(hm, key_2, string_2, resolve_collision);
    assert(memcmp(get_data(hm, key_2), string_2, mystrlen(string_2)) == 0);

    // Insert ("ad" -> "Software").
    insert_data(hm, key_3, string_3, resolve_collision);
    assert(memcmp(get_data(hm, key_3), string_3, mystrlen(string_3)) == 0);

    // Insert ("ab" -> "Embedded").
    insert_data(hm, key_1, string_2, resolve_collision);
    assert(memcmp(get_data(hm, key_1), string_2, mystrlen(string_2)) == 0);

    // Get data for a not inserted key.
    assert(get_data(hm, key_4) == NULL);

    // Iterate the hash map
    iterate(hm, print_element);

    #ifdef NEW_HASH
    set_hash_function(hm, your_own_hash);

    printf("\nHERE WE GO AGAIN!\n\n");

    // Iterate the hash map 
    iterate(hm, print_element);
    #endif

    // Delete key "ab".
    remove_data(hm, key_1, NULL);
    assert(get_data(hm, key_1) == NULL);

    // Delete key "cd".
    remove_data(hm, key_2, NULL);
    assert(get_data(hm, key_2) == NULL);

    // Delete key "ad".
    remove_data(hm, key_3, NULL);
    assert(get_data(hm, key_3) == NULL);

    // Delete the hash map.
    delete_hashmap(hm, NULL);

    #ifdef COUNTING_WORDS
    // Create a temporary file
    FILE *stream = tmpfile();

    // Write to the stream
    fprintf(stream, "foo bar_, baz!\n");
    fprintf(stream, "foo\t\"bar\".\n");
    fprintf(stream, "foo?\n");

    // Set the position to the start of the stream
    fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Count the words
    count_words(stream);

    // Close the file
    fclose(stream);
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

The output I´m getting is:

```
("ab", Embedded)
("ab", TI2725-C)
("ad", Software)
("cd", Embedded)
```

While it should give me this:

```
("ab", TI2725-C)
("cd", Embedded)
("ad", Software)
("ab", Embedded)
```

What I've noticed is that the result I get is somehow sorted in alphabetic order and, to my knowledge, that is not what a hashmap is supposed to do. I think there is something wrong with my linked list, which is set in the insert_data() function or there is something wrong with reading the data in the get_data() function. Can anybody help me out?

In addition, we have to use valgrind as our debugging tool and whenever I use it, it tells me I have 10 allocs and 9 frees and it tells me that the malloc at the strdup function has never been free'd, I've read that the malloc at the strdup function is a tricky one to free and I still haven´t figured that one out. Can someone help me with this as well?

Comment: this might help if you have time http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/

Comment: A professor of C course told you to teach yourself C ??? And his job is what?

Comment: Are you sure the order is important for testing? I think it should be fine, as it is passing all of the `assert`s

Comment: Can you provide any reference a map must **not** be sorted?

Comment: @titus I´ve read their tutorials over and over, but they seem to have a different application to the hashmap than I have to do.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Dude, you have no idea what I´m going through because of that man. Anyhow, I handed it in like this and as a response he said that I had to fix it, so apparently it is important enough for the prof

Comment: @Olaf. I read somewhere that a hashmap stores stuff randomly while a treemap stores stuff in some kind of order, may it be alphabetical or in order of integer size. Maybe this isn´t true, I don´t know :)

Comment: A hashmap **never** stores data _randomly_ (be careful with that term), but uses an algorithm to calculate the hash. But even **if** it was randomly, why wouldn't that include storing keys sorted by chance?

Comment: your function `remove_data()` wipes out the entire chain where `key` happens to be part of. (Hint: use a pointer to pointer to simplify things)

Comment: @Olaf. It shouldn´t matter if the keys were stored by chance, keeping in mind if it stored the keys randomly. But now I know this is not the case. Thank you

Comment: @joop. Thanks for the tip, although I don´t really know what you´re hinting. Bear in mind that I only know the basics, so I know what a pointer to a pointer is and I think I know how to implement it, but where should I use it then and what pointer do I have to point to?

Comment: @IsaElDoori: To emphasise again: They are **not** stored randomly. In a computer it is very difficult to get random values (and the keys are not even stored pseudo-randomly)  Inspect your key-calculation algorithm. Use a debugger to check your map during execution.

Comment: Side-note: Why did you implement your own `strdup`? It's [provided on the vast majorities of systems](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup); no need to write your own.

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings,  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.  (I also use `-std=c99 -Wconversion` )

Comment: Regarding the returned pointer from `strdup()`,  just pass it to `free()` like any other allocated memory.  Nothing 'tricky' about it.

Comment: I would expect the code provided by the teacher to cleanly compile.  However, regarding this function: `void *resolve_collision(void *old_value, void *new_value) {`  The parameter `old_value` is not used, which causes the compiler to raise a warning.  The teacher could easily have eliminated that warning by inserting a `(void)old_value;` statement in the function.

Comment: It seems your working on the linux (or similar) OS.  The function you wrote: `strdup()` can be eliminated by having the first line of your hashtable.c file be: `#define _GNU_SOURCE`  Then the `strdup()` defined in <string.h> will be used.

Comment: when calling `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`,  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the loop beginning with: `while(next)` in the function: `remove_data()` will only be executed once.  Is that what you actually want?

Comment: It seems to me that you are wrong about the output that should be given. I think that the `Insert ("ab" -> "Embedded")` should not add a second entry with the already present key `ab`, but rather replace the previously inserted entry `("ab" -> "TI2725-C")`. Are you sure that it's not this what the professor wanted you to fix?